# Xorg self changing scan-out/rendering buffer before outputting

Tags: video, rendering, driver, framebuffer, xorg

I have non typical question.
For example I have PC with 2 projectors connected to it.
I use XRANDR to cat two displays (2 projectors) to one virtual screen.

So, as I understand I have two scan-out buffers for each projector.
Each buffer contains RGB pixels, that will be outputted via Video Card.

I want to manipulate pixels before it will be scan out, but after xserver will render hole picture.

My question is How to do it? 
I think I must add a hook somewhere, but where? What level of software I must change?
Somewhere in the kernel? Or I can change somewhere in xserver side?

All information will be usefull. Thanks!